# TypeError: Reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, reduce

I'm currently trying to write a function that will give me a tuple whose 0 index is the amount of lines in that file, and whose 1 index is how many characters are in that file. So far, I have a list of tuples, which looks like this:

```
mapped = [(1, 50), (1, 11), (1, 58)]
```

The line I'm trying to write is this:

```
reduce(lambda x:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]),(i for i in mapped))
```

If it works correctly, then it should return a tuple of (3, 119). However, I'm getting an error of

```
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Can anybody figure out why this is?

Comment: Unable to reproduce (Python 3.4.2)

Comment: This error also occurs when you try to reduce an empty map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]),[i for i in mapped])
(3, 119)
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]),(i for i in mapped))
(3, 119)
```

What you miss is that `lambda` should take two parameters, you just give one.

For Python3.x see the code below:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]),(i for i in mapped))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]),(i for i in mapped))
(3, 119)
```

Answer (score 19):

Nobody answer why there is an error:

`TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value`

When the list literal which is second parameter is empty, the error occurs. So if you try

`reduce(lambda x, y:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]), [])`

You'll get the error.

Answer (score 7):

`map(sum, ...)` fits better, looks beautiful.

```
map(sum, zip(*mapped))
```

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) if lengths of the lists are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]),(i for i in mapped))
```

That's probably what you want, or at least that's what got me the output you were expecting; you have to add the `,y` in the lambda expression to tell it that there will be two parameters.